# Java - adding to lists before/after item X

Tags: java, list

I want to add items to a list representing a high-score table in a way that would maintain it as an ordered list regardless of exact implementation. Specifically, given item X in the list, I want to be able to put a new item right after X, without running over (that is deleting) any existing items.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'regardless of exact implementation'? If I'm reading your question right, you are implementing the list with a particular requirement. You can always have a sorted list of entries and every time you add an entry to it.

Comment: I basically want to be able to do it without caring what exact implementation of List is used. If impossible, what implementation is best used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interface `List` has a method [`add(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-).

First find the index of item X in the list, for example using the [`indexOf(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) method, then use this method to insert an item before or after X.

About `List` implementations: inserting elements at arbitrary positions is more efficient in a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) than in an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Does it move the objects in the indices that follow it forward without running over the object that was in that index previously?

Comment: @Sunspawn Read the API documentation by clicking on the links in my answer.